# Delphi appearance of hint when hovering the mouse in dbgrid

Tags: delphi-7, dbgrid

How to do it, what would happen when we hover the mouse cursor in dbgrid, if the field has the desired value, would a hint appear?

```
if qry1.fieldbyname('PASSENGER_TYPE').asstring = 'INF' then
  dbgrd1.Hint := 'младенец';
```

Rummaged in the properties of dbgrid made in ShowHint = True. All has earned, BUT when not on value and when I cause the cursor in dbgrid how to make that was when I am directing on value itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to customize any control's hint is to either:

1. assign an event handler to the `TApplication(Events).OnShowHint` event, which has `HintStr` and `HintInfo` parameters that you can customize as needed.
2. subclass the control itself to intercept the `CM_HINTSHOW` message.  The `LPARAM` will be a pointer to a `THintInfo` that you can customize as needed.